# How to calculate Monthly Recurring Revenue using DAX?

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop, crm, daxstudio

My end goal is to have a Monthly Recurring Revenue for a subscription service. Example:

Rules:

- Contract column must be different than 0
- The following table is already related to the calendar dimension using another column.

**CRMTable**

| Contract | ContractDate | ContractEnd | Revenue |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| X | 01/01/2023 | 01/06/2023 | 1000 |
| 0 | 01/02/2023 | 01/07/2023 | 1000 |
| X | 01/03/2023 | 01/08/2023 | 1000 |
| X | 01/04/2023 | 01/09/2023 | 1000 |
| X | 01/05/2023 | 01/10/2023 | 1000 |

The goal is to have this result:

| Month | Revenue |
| ----- | ------- |
| 01/2023 | 1000 |
| 02/2023 | 1000 |
| 03/2023 | 2000 |
| 04/2023 | 3000 |
| 05/2023 | 4000 |
| 06/2023 | 3000 |
| 07/2023 | 3000 |
| 08/2023 | 2000 |
| 09/2023 | 1000 |
| 10/2023 | 0 |
...

And then display it in a line graph. But I don't know how to calculate this. Already used chatGPT but it didn't help much.

Thanks in advance!

I tried using this but it doesn't add monthly.

```
MRR = CALCULATE(SUM(CRMTable[Revenue]), CRMTable[Contract] <> "0")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have developed this based on an unrelated, single-column table which comprises the first day of each month, e.g. 01/01/2023, 01/02/2023, etc. You can then create a Pivot Table using these months together with the following measure:

```
=
VAR ThisDate =
    MIN( Months[Month] )
RETURN
    SUMX(
        FILTER(
            CRMTable,
            CRMTable[Contract] <> "0"
                && CRMTable[ContractDate] <= EOMONTH( ThisDate, 0 )
                && CRMTable[ContractEnd] > ThisDate
        ),
        CRMTable[Revenue]
    )
```